# Extract first and last timestamps of sequences of consecutive timestamps in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a column 'timestamp' containing datetimes. The timestamps are all rounded to the minute and the dataframe is sorted ascending on this column. I am looking for the first and last timestamps of all sequences of consecutive timestamps that contain at least five timestamps. With 'sequence of consecutive timestamps' I mean a series of timestamps that are just one minute apart. For instance in the example dataframe, row 1 to 5 would be a sequence as well as row 6 to 7.

Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2022-10-06 16:21:00', '2022-10-06 16:25:00', '2022-10-06 16:26:00',
                                 '2022-10-06 16:27:00', '2022-10-06 16:28:00', '2022-10-06 16:29:00',
                                 '2022-10-06 16:36:00', '2022-10-06 16:37:00'],
                   'data': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla']})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

             timestamp data
0  2022-10-06 16:21:00  bla
1  2022-10-06 16:25:00  bla
2  2022-10-06 16:26:00  bla
3  2022-10-06 16:27:00  bla
4  2022-10-06 16:28:00  bla
5  2022-10-06 16:29:00  bla
6  2022-10-06 16:36:00  bla
7  2022-10-06 16:37:00  bla
                  ...   ...
```

My desired output is a list containing all first and last timestamps of all sequences that are at least five rows long:

```
[[2022-10-06 16:25:00, 2022-10-06 16:29:00], ...]
```

I managed to find the time difference in minutes between consecutive rows using:

```
df['delta'] = (df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

Resulting in:

```
            timestamp data  delta
0 2022-10-06 16:21:00  bla    NaN
1 2022-10-06 16:25:00  bla    4.0
2 2022-10-06 16:26:00  bla    1.0
3 2022-10-06 16:27:00  bla    1.0
4 2022-10-06 16:28:00  bla    1.0
5 2022-10-06 16:29:00  bla    1.0
6 2022-10-06 16:36:00  bla    7.0
7 2022-10-06 16:37:00  bla    1.0
                  ...   ...    ...
```

But I'm still struggling to extract the first and last timestamp.

How can I efficiently extract the first and last timestamps of a sequence of consecutive timestamps? Is using the timedifference the best way and if so, how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can you tell where each sequence begins and ends? Is there different information in the 'data' column?

Comment: I edited my question according to your comment by elaborating on how I interpret sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in `'ind'` get he index of the rows where, the current value is not equal to 1, and the next is equal to 1. That is, we get the (beginning of the sequence). In the `'aaa'` list, these indices are passed to the function, where the `dataframe slice df.loc[x:]` is taken. Find the nearest index where the current value is 1 and the next is not (end of sequence). And as a result, the list `'aaa'` is filtered by `aaa[:, 2] >= 5`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['delta'] = df['timestamp'].dt.minute.diff()

ind = df[(df['delta'].shift(-1) == 1) & (df['delta'] != 1)].index


def f(x):
    bbb = df.loc[x:]
    first = bbb.loc[x, 'timestamp']
    last_ind = bbb.loc[(bbb['delta'].shift(-1) != 1) & (bbb['delta'] == 1), 'timestamp'].index

    return [first, bbb.loc[last_ind[0], 'timestamp'], bbb.loc[x:last_ind[0], 'delta'].count()]


aaa = np.array([f(i) for i in ind])

print(aaa[aaa[:, 2] >= 5, :2])
```

Output

```
[[Timestamp('2022-10-06 16:25:00') Timestamp('2022-10-06 16:29:00')]]
```

**Update 06.05.2023**

Another option. It will probably work faster (especially true for large datasets). Here, `'delta'` is set to 0 for differences of 1. For the first row of the sequence, 1 is set. In df1, rows are taken where there is 1 or 0. Through assign, a cs column is created that calculates the `cumulative sum` for marking sequences into [groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

[Aggregates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) are counted for each group: 'first', 'last', 'count'.

```
df['delta'] = df['timestamp'].dt.minute.diff().replace(1, 0)
df.loc[(df['delta'].shift(-1) == 0) & (df['delta'] != 0), 'delta'] = 1


df1 = df[(df['delta'] == 0) | (df['delta'] == 1)].\
    assign(cs=df['delta'].cumsum()).groupby('cs')['timestamp'].\
    agg(['first', 'last', 'count']).reset_index(drop=True)


print(df1.loc[df1['count'] >= 5, ['first', 'last']].values)
```